# XPathResult not getting first result

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

When I run the below JS only **P** elements with **hello** in it will appear except the first one, why won't the first one show up?

JS:

```
        queryResult = 1;

    function testQuery() {
        queryResult = "hello";
        if (queryResult == "") {
            return false;
        }
        $("p").css("display", "none");
        var headings = document.evaluate("//p[contains(., '" + queryResult + "')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();
        while (thisHeading) {
            var thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();
            $(thisHeading).css("display", "block");

        }
    }
```

html:

```
<body onload="testQuery();">
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>goodbye</p>
    <p>hello there</p>
    <p>goodbye friend</p>
</body>
```

Comment: What does `document` html look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in terms of returning the correct `<p>` nodes, try changing the relevant part of your code to:

```
queryResult = "hello";
exp = `//p[contains(., "${queryResult}")]`
var headings = document.evaluate(exp, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE);

while(thisHeading = headings.iterateNext()) {
  console.log(thisHeading);
}
```

Output should be the 3 relevant `<p>` nodes.